# Changing embedded serial number

Tags: embedded, hex

I have a Serial number string "1080910" embedded in a programmable device which has been downloaded to a binary file using the ALL-100 programmer. This is my Master file as it were. I need to change this serial number to that of the unit that I need to re-flash using the Master file - the ALL-100 programmer uses XACCESS User Interface which has Edit feature showing Address location, Hex data field and Ascii field. Somewhere in this file is the serial number string - can anybody assist me in how to locate and edit the serial number string as I have been unable to locate it using the search function and have not been able to visually pick up the sequence of numbers.  Help !!!

Comment: Maybe you should better use an hexadecimal editor (google for this) to edit the binary file, and resend it to your device

Answer (score 2):

If the data has a symbolic address in the source code, and is not a local variable, its address will appear in the map file generated by the linker. If it is a local variable initialised with a literal constant, then the data will exist in the static initialisation data the location of which should also be identified in the map file.

Another possibility is that your application image is compressed and the start-up code expands it into RAM at run-time.  This will be obvious in the map file if the data and code addresses are in RAM rather than ROM.  If this is the case then what you are attempting will be very difficult.  You would have to know the compression algorithm used, and which part of the image is the commpressed part (part of it will be the decompression code that runs from ROM).  You would then have to decompress the image, modify the string, and then recompress it.  Further, if the decompression performs any kind of checksum on the compressed or decompressed data, you will have to recalculate and modify that too.

If this was a requirement from the outset, you would have done better to reserve the space in the linker script or use compiler specific extensions to absolutely locate the data at a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is stored in [Unicod](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)e, so alternate chars are 00.